# ACL checks at API level, on a per-method basis

Tags: php, model-view-controller, acl

I'm working on a sort of MVC framework, and I'm implementing a simple ACL permissions check system.

I'm wondering if anyone can shed some light on, or direct me towards some good examples of this sort of implementation (or criticize to the point of warranting scrapping it, whichever is necessary)

Since I'm building the framework with REST API in mind, I've created two base controllers, `WebController` and `ApiController`.

Requests made to `/index.php` route to `WebController_*` and requests made to `/api/index.php` route to `ApiController_*`

An extended `WebController` is responsible for building output from a template with data returned from the consolidated calls to the necessary `ApiController`s.

An extended `ApiController` is responsible for querying the `Model` for data. If a call is made directly to `/api/index.php` it returns `JSON`.

**But I digress;** In order to facilitate ACL, I figured implementing it at the `ApiController` layer made sense, and if there is a denial it is returned in `JSON` or back up to a `WebController` and handled accordingly, depending on the request type.

I'm thinking to simplify things, I could make use of `__call()` and *private* methods. `__call()` would verify the existence of the requested method, and prior to calling it, check the user permissions on the method it against the ACL.

```
class ApiController{

    public function __call($method, $arguments){
        if(method_exists($this, $method)){
            //haven't written ACL classes yet, but something like this
            if(ACL::check(...)){ 
                return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $arguments);
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            //throw catchable exception or something
        }
    }

}
```

*Good idea? Bad idea? Thoughts?* Maybe I'm in over my head here, I'm still learning and this is more for education than profit, however finishing something that has future use would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to go with an approach similar to my initially proposed method, creating a `Gateway` object to act as a proxy to the `Model`. Essentially the `Gateway` object holds a reference to the `Acl`, `Request`, and `Model` objects, and performs checks against the `Acl` object before forwarding any method calls to the `Model`. Simplified for brevity:

```
public function __call($method, $arguments){
    // check request data against acl
    if($this->_acl->check($this->_request, $method, $arguments)){
        // on success, send request in and forward method to model
        $this->_model->setRequest($this->_request);
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->_model, $method), $arguments);
    }
    // acl check failed, no access
    return false;
}
```

**Are there any issues that can be seen with this approach?** So far as I can tell, this should serve the purpose quite effectively, as I can sub in different `Acl` and `Model` objects based on the needs of the `Controller` (Though likely there will only be the need for a single `Acl`)

Furthermore, my routing of API calls becomes simplified, as using a REST/RPC hybrid architecture, API calls can be passed to the `Gateway` without much need for modification.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty good idea to check credentials in the `ApiController` layer but try to kill the magic by avoiding the `__call()` method. Yes, this isn't your question but could be useful if you want better performances.

Well, you may use **filters** like a *security filter* which handles the request and check the user permissions. The filter could redirect the request to the 401 error response for example.
This idea comes from the [Symfony Framework](http://www.symfony-project.org).

Regards,
William.

Comment: **Thanks William**; I'm trying to avoid hard-calling ACL check methods, whether it's prior to the `ApiController` method call, or *in* the `ApiController` method call. I've been reading about the Observer pattern, and perhaps that's the direction I should take. `__call()` seemed like a good idea, but if there are other ways to force this type of behavior, I'm all ears.

Comment: Yes the Observer pattern is a nice way.Here is a good implementation in PHP : [Event dispatcher](http://components.symfony-project.org/event-dispatcher/).